# How to disable wide soundstage DSP on Macbook Air M1 (Macos Sonoma)?

Tags: macos, audio

**TLDR: is there any way to disable or limit audio processing on a Mac when playing on internal speakers?**

My M1 Air does some kind of audio processing, seeming always, which can make the sound stage seem much wider than the physical computer.  With YouTube and movies it's usually a benefit, as some sounds seem to come from far left or right of the computer.  It does this so convincingly that I have often paused the playback to check if I was hearing something else happening in the room.  When it is a beneficial effect, it is amazing.  But when it doesn't work well, it arguably ruins the (music) sound.

Sony was one of the early consumer audio companies that would offer effects like "wide", "theater", etc. which did some kind of processing to make the sound seem wider than the source.  These days, such processing effects are common.  I mention this because it may help some readers recognize the impact on sound that I'm referring to.

Usually on the Mac this sounds great, but **sometimes it can hide the vocals and make the sound seem distant and vague**.  When this happens, it's definitely not a benefit and would be better disabled.

When Airpods are connected, there are some effects options; with other headphones there are no options but also apparently no spacial effects processing - just pure left/right.  But when using the internal speakers, there seem to be nothing but left/right balance and volume options.